# Reading DynamoDB streams in batches

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Here is a simplified version of an API, that I am developing. Different users can create, update and delete entities of some kind. And I need to periodically prepare or update one ZIP file per customer, containing the latest versions of their entities.

My idea is to store the entities in a DynamoDB table and then periodically run a batch process, which would read the changes from the table's stream. My question is how do I make sure that each subsequent batch read would continue from the correct place? That is, from the first unread event.

A bit more info:

- I need to run this outside of an AWS Lambda function.
- I prefer to use a DynamoDB stream, not a Kinesis data stream for this, if possible.
- I know I can put a timestamp in the table and just read from the latest timestamp that I had (that is, not using streams at all). There are some synchronization problems with this.
- I had implemented this before by using a second table to act like a journal. While this works, it's a bit clunky, so I wanted to see if I can use streams for this.
- My program is in Java, but I won't mind hints for other languages or even direct API calls.

This is kind of a follow-up question to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010290/106350.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With streams you have an iterator position per shard, in which you can use as a pointer to the last read position. You can read more on this here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html#Streams.Processing

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetShardIterator.html

Comment: I read that iterators are valid for 15 minutes, which means that they are not really usable for my use-case. Also, I couldn't find a way to obtain the position within the iterator, to be able to use it with [GetShardIterator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetShardIterator.html).

Comment: Yes the iterator expires but you can request a new one at any time by specifying the Sequence Number returned in the Record https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_StreamRecord.html#DDB-Type-streams_StreamRecord-SequenceNumber

Comment: Thank you! At least in the Java API the sequence number is a bit hidden. To get it I had to call `record.dynamodb().sequenceNumber()`. Not that bad, but I didn't think to look for it in the record in the first place as I assumed it's a property of the shard or the iterator. A mention in the docs would be great!

Just to confirm, I am now remembering the (shard ID, sequence number). Next time I run it, I skip the shards until I find the one I remembered and I get an iterator with the sequence number. Is that the right approach? (It worked in my small test, but I'm still not 100% sure).

Comment: Yes that is correct. Also on the documentation, please provide feedback directly which you can see a link to on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a FIFO queue?

```
Dynamo Stream -> Lambda -> SNS (If more than one consumer) -> FIFO SQS
```

Then your application can subscribe to the SQS and update the zips. The FIFO queue will guarantee order.

And BTW I am 99% sure that dynamo stream is actually a hidden kinesis stream, because it has the same configuration, they just don't state it plainly in the docs

Comment: Your assumption that DynamoDB streams is Kinesis is wrong. DynamoDB provides both DynamoDB Streams and Kinesis Data Streams both if which provide different features.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it may work, but it uses Lambda, which I didn't want to use. Also it has additional dependencies (SNS, SQS), which make it a more involved solution than the one I was looking for.